# Filter will not work with AngularStrap bs-select and ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angular-strap, angular-filters

I'm attempting to filter the list of available options in a bs-select dropdown list using the ng-options directive per AngularStrap's specifications.  I'm simply using their example like so.

**HTML**:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-model="selectedIcon" 
    data-html="1"
    data-multiple="1" 
    ng-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in icons | filter:iconSearch"
    bs-select>
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="iconSearch" />
```

**Controller (index.js)**:

```
$scope.selectedIcons = [];
$scope.icons = [
    {"value":"Gear","label":"<i class=\"fa fa-gear\"></i> Gear"},
    {"value":"Globe","label":"<i class=\"fa fa-globe\"></i> Globe"},
    {"value":"Heart","label":"<i class=\"fa fa-heart\"></i> Heart"},
    {"value":"Camera","label":"<i class=\"fa fa-camera\"></i> Camera"}
];
```

**Problem**
When I begin typing in the input box (i.e. iconSearch begins to change), the list of available options in the AngularStrap drop-down does not change.  If I "hardcode" the filter in ng-options to read `... | filter: 'Gear'` it will work just fine on page load.

If I add the following code to the view, I can see that the array of icons **is** being filtered correctly.

```
<pre>{{icons | filter:iconSearch | json}}</pre>
```

**Question**

1. Is it even possible to filter the options array dynamically and have bs-select respond accordingly?
2. If so, how?  If not, how can this be altered to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that filter does not get evaluated to generate the option list. You could instead do the filtering in the controller.

In your controller:

```
  $scope.getIcons = function() {
     return filterFilter(icons, $scope.iconSearch);
  }
```

In your view:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-model="selectedIcon" 
   data-html="1" data-multiple="1" 
   ng-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in getIcons()" bs-select>
        Action <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="iconSearch.value" />
```

```js
angular.module('app', ['mgcrea.ngStrap', 'ngSanitize']).controller('ctrl', function($scope, filterFilter) {

  $scope.selectedIcons = [];
  
  var icons = [{
    "value": "Gear",
    "label": "<i class=\"fa fa-gear\"></i> Gear"
  }, {
    "value": "Globe",
    "label": "<i class=\"fa fa-globe\"></i> Globe"
  }, {
    "value": "Heart",
    "label": "<i class=\"fa fa-heart\"></i> Heart"
  }, {
    "value": "Camera",
    "label": "<i class=\"fa fa-camera\"></i> Camera"
  }];

  $scope.getIcons = function() {
     return filterFilter(icons, $scope.iconSearch);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.1.5/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.1.5/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-model="selectedIcon" data-html="1" data-multiple="1" ng-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in getIcons()" bs-select>
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="iconSearch.value" />
 
</div>
```

Comment: @dfsq Yeah i was actually surprised too. I have never used filters on the view with ng-option before though. I believe the regex for ng-option expression parser ignores filter

Comment: Well filters work fine with ngOptions, looks like the problem with AngularStrap. Anyway you found a workaround to use a controller.

Comment: Yeah you are right, looks like the issue is with `var watchedOptions = parsedOptions.$match[7].replace(/\|.+/, '').trim();
        scope.$watch(watchedOptions, function(newValue, oldValue) {` in bsSelect code it does watch only `icons` on the scope and updates dom. Filters gets ignored.. So either set `scope.icons` and on keyup event update icons with filter or provide a getter method, that's all i can see as workarounds.